# Calling a class method in class attribute

Tags: python

I want to make a class that contains collection of colored signs, and I want it to be like a static variable. But I can't call @classmethod from the class attribute, i.e. the following gives me error (`NameError: name 'Pegs' is not defined`):

```
class Color:
    RED = '\033[31m'

class Pegs:
    PEG = '\u25A0'
    PEGS = {
        'red' : Pegs.generate_peg_from_color(Color.RED)
    }

    @classmethod
    def generate_peg_from_color(cls, color):
        return ''.join([color, Pegs.PEG])
```

Is it possible to call a function in a class attribute? Should I use static method decorator instead of class method? And why does it generates this error?

Comment: No, you can't do this; Pegs is still in the process of being defined at the point you're trying to reference it.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to manually define all colors?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pegs:

    PEG = '\u25A0'

    @classmethod
    def generate_peg_from_color(cls, color):
        return ''.join([color, cls.PEG])

    PEGS = {
        'red' : Pegs.generate_peg_from_color(Color.RED)
    }
```

You were trying to call function before it is defined. Now you can try it:

```
In [11]: Pegs.PEGS
Out[11]: {'red': '\x1b[31m■'}
```

**UPDATE^**

What if you'll add such method:

```
@classmethod
def meth(cls):
    cls.PEGS = {
        'red': cls.generate_peg_from_color(Color.RED)
    }
```

And reach your class attributes after that? Will this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks py_dude, but this wont work if I try to import it.

Comment: No, it wont solve (then I'd have to call the class method, or instantiate an object and then generate colors. but I want to have them as static variables), thanks for helping, but the more I think about it, the more i think that I'll have to delete this question.